# R code error when extract information from a list of files: arguments imply differing number of rows

Tags: r, list, dataframe, bind, rbind

I have a list of files and want to extract some information from each sheet.

I tried code as below:

```
list2022 = list.files(path= "Z:/2022/", "^analysis*", full.names = TRUE)
list2021 = list.files(path= "Z:/2021/", "^analysis*", full.names = TRUE)
list2020 = list.files(path= "Z:/2020/", "^analysis*", full.names = TRUE)

co <- c(list2022,list2020,list2021)

data <- lapply(co, function(x) read.xlsx(x, sheetIndex = 13, startRow = 8, cols = 11:17, rows = 9:10))%>%
  set_names(combo)%>% bind_rows(.id = 'Date')
```

But got an error:

Error in data.frame(res, ...) :
arguments imply differing number of rows: 5, 7, 2

And weird part is I ran this code successfully yesterday, but got this error today. The only thing I changed is sheet= "duration" to sheetIndex= 13, cuz I got an error : argument 2 matches multiple formal arguments

Any one can help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the path are the same, how do you expect it to have different files.  Also, `co` is a `vector` of files.  Use `co <- list(list2022, list2020 list2021)` as `list.files` returns a vector of file

Comment: I just removed the whole path in the question, actually they are from different folder, so I need to read them separately. If I use list((list2022, list2020 list2021), co would be a list of 4 list, and following command will cause a warning: In if (!file.exists(path.expand(file))) stop("Cannot find ", path.expand(file)) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: If you want to read all the files in each of the list, you may need nested lapply i.e. `lapply(co, function(files) lapply(files, function(x) read.xlsx(x,..` assuming `co <- list(list2022, ...)`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I just tried the nested lapply, but still got the same error: Error in data.frame(res, ...) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 5, 7, 2

Comment: i think it has to do with `bind_rows` it should be inside the outer list

Comment: ye, I used bind_rows in my code, but I don't know where went wrong

Comment: Try `co <- dplyr::lst(list2022, list2020, list2021); library(purrr);map_dfr(co, ~ map_dfr(setNames(.x, .x), ~ read.xlsx(.x, sheetIndex = 13, startRow = 8, cols = 11:17, rows = 9:10), .id = 'file_name'), .id = 'listname')`

Comment: same error... : Error in data.frame(res, ...) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 19, 7, 2  (FYI: I restarted R, so it might be the reason it shows 19 instead of 5?)

Comment: It should have worked.  Without a reproducible example, it is not clear why you get the error